# PTIJ: Was Yitzchak Breslov?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I've been pondering which type of Jew each of the Avos was and I think I have proof to one of them. Genesis 24:63 states,
וַיֵּצֵ֥א יִצְחָ֛ק לָשׂ֥וּחַ בַּשָּׂדֶ֖ה לִפְנ֣וֹת עָ֑רֶב
-"Yitzchak went out to converse in the field towards evening"
Isn't it strange how the Pasuk specifies **"Field"**? We find the אבן עזרא there explains. "ללכת בין השיחים"- "to speak among the trees". I think its quite fair to say that Yitchak was A breslover Chassid, though I'm wondering if he was a na nach too....

Comment: This question does not fulfill the requirement of a Purim Torah post that it have a caveat appended. See the policy linked above. (Moreover, IMO, it's not a question so much as a statement with a question mark appended.)

Answer (score 3):

He must of been a na nach as you find these words being mentioned about Yitzchak in the pesukim:

> וַיֹּ֡אמֶר קַח־**נָ֠א** אֶת־בִּ**נְךָ֨** אֶת־יְחִֽידְךָ֤ אֲשֶׁר־אָהַ֙בְתָּ֙ אֶת־**יִצְחָ֔ק**

> וַיִּ**נָּחֵ֥ם יִצְחָ֖ק** אַחֲרֵ֥י אִמּֽוֹ

> וְאַל־תַּ֥עַשׂ ל֖וֹ **מְא֑וּמָה**